# Are these float attributes macros specific to GCC?

Tags: c++, floating-point, macros

I am using GCC and my compiler defines those macros : `__FLT_RADIX__`, `__FLT_MANT_DIG__`, `__FLT_MAX_EXP__`, `__FLT_HAS_INFINITY__`, `__FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__`, `__FLT_HAS_DENORM__`, ... Are they specific to GCC or are they in the C++ standard ? I mean wether they are defined or not, I know their values are implementation-specific. If they are not in the standard, where can I find their equivalent for all compilers ?

Comment: Search here (without the leading and trailing `__`) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits  `__` in names are reserved for the implementation to use.

Comment: You should be able to find their equivalents, if there are any, in each respective compiler's documentation or header files.

Comment: `__FLT_HAS_INFINITY__` and `__FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__` are not defined int climits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they ... in the C++ standard ?

No.

> Are they specific to GCC

They are not in GCC documentation, so they are not guaranteed to be in (future releases of) GCC either. They are for internal use (probably for portable implementation of the standard macros and `std::numeric_limits`).

> where can I find their equivalent for all compilers ?

There are corresponding standard macros for most of these in the C standard library. Simply remove the underscores from beginning and end; for example `FLT_RADIX`. An exception is `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` which is named differently as you can see. See the standard for full list of macros.

There are no standard macros for `__FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__` or `__FLT_HAS_INFINITY__`. But the information (including the others) is in `std::numeric_limits` template.

---

> I need to use those values in the preprocessor

> It there a ways of using std::numiric_limits constants in the preprocessor

You could use metaprogramming. Write a program that generates a header file with custom macro definitions. Something like

```
std::cout << "#define MY_CUSTOM_FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN "
          << std::numeric_limits<float>::has_quiet_NaN();
```

Then compile and run that meta program on the target system to generate the header to use to compile the main program.

Comment: I need to use those values in the preprocessor, that's why I can't use `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: It there a ways of using `std::numiric_limits` constants in the preprocessor or something similar ?

Comment: Can I use static_assert ?

Comment: @linternetsansfil Yes. You don't need macros to use static_assert.